# I need to extract third word in all lines from file in perl

Tags: perl

I have a text file with following data:

```
    1122322 Kiran India Bombay
    3212232 Ashlie China Beijing 
    2312322 Polly USA Washington
```

How can I use a perl script to extract just the third word (Country) in all lines. Would really appreciate your help

Comment: Can country names have whitespace in them? How are the columns delimited? Have a look at [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can

```
perl -lane 'print $F[2]' file
```

Comment: @user3467773 what output did you get?